# Get child without changes from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I want to implement a chat function. For each chat a unique chatID is created, that needs to be fetched when it‘s started. I read about using the `ListenerForSingleValueEvent()` to get a `dataSnapshot`, but it seems to only be reached when there‘s a data change. How can I fetch the data from a child without the need to changing something?

Like this, I don‘t get my chatID:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String chatId;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser, mDatabaseChat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("ChatId");
        mDatabaseChat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
        getChatId();
    }
 
    private void getChatId(){
        mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    chatId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    mDatabaseChat = mDatabaseChat.child(chatId);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onDataChange` fires right away (well... within a few seconds) with the current value, and then subsequently on any change. If that doesn't happen for you, implement `onCancelled` for example as `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: I thought so too, but for some reason is just skipped. The listener is triggered but jumps straight at the end and doesn’t consider `onDataChange()`or `onCancelled()`

Comment: If you runt the code in a debugger, and place a breakpoint on `if (dataSnapshot.exists()){`, does the debugger hit that breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, the breakpoint is reached and the listener is called. but then it doesn’t jump to the onDataChange or onCancelled, but to the end bracket of the listener

Comment: That sounds like there is no data under `getReference().child("Users").child("ChatId")`. It's impossible to say why that is without seeing your database, but an educated guess is that you're missing a `.child(uid)` in there. If that's not it, update your question to include the JSON yuo're trying to read here (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: That’s a good idea, I checked it quickly already before, but I‘m gonna look more detailed now at first if the issue is there

Comment: You were right, a parameter hasn’t been passed and included into the query properly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addValueEventListner method to get the values from the firebase realtime database.

```
private void getChatId() { 
    DatabaseReference firebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(dbPath);
    //dbPath is the path of the data stored in firebase required to receive
    firebaseDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Refer the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Is it triggered on every change or only once? I thought the ListenerForSingleValueEvent is appropriate, because I just need the possibility to fetch it once?

Comment: It will trigger every time when the data changes.

Comment: But what do I need to do to get the data when there‘s no change necessary? Like just fetching that id?

Comment: I think you have a separate issue where the firebase call is happening asynchronously. So it will not wait in the firebase call.

Comment: Do you have an idea what to do or how to fix it? Can I make it wait for it?

Comment: This won't solve the problem (or at least: shouldn't). Using `addValueEventListener`  functions the same as `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` when it comes to loading the initial data. The only difference is that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` disconnects straight after getting the initial data, while `addValueEventListener` keeps listening.